# Keep form always on top of taskbar

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to keep a form always on top of the taskbar, but whenever the taskbar is selected/becomes focused, my form goes behind it. I already have it set to topmost (me.topmost = true), but it would appear this doesn't keep it always on top.

How would I keep my form **always** on top of the taskbar and keep it on top when the taskbar is focused?

Comment: I don't think the reason is important here, but my reason is that I'm creating a start menu for Windows 8/8.1. I already have the form following the taskbar on every side of the screen and I have a method nudge over the taskbar icons to make room for the start button. All I need now is to keep the form always on top of the taskbar to make it usable

Comment: The taskbar also has the TopMost property so it can be accessible to the user.  You are asking for a SuperDuperTopMost feature.  Everybody asks for that.  And everybody will use it too, making the feature useless.  So of course Microsoft won't add it.  You cannot get what you want.

Comment: The correct way to build a start menu for Windows is by a shell extension, not a separate process. You can do this in .NET now, see here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7ceb44d5-dce8-4197-ac55-f0f4fb59eeb4/how-can-i-write-managed-shell-extension-in-net-4

Answer (score 1):

I have figure out a way to keep the form on top of the taskbar. To do this, you must have the form set as top most:

```
me.topmost = true
```

Next, you want to create a timer and have the interval to be 1. The timer will constantly keep the start button focused:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Me.Focus()
End Sub
```

That's it, the form will stay on top of the taskbar even if the taskbar becomes focused.