# How to display seconds in the system tray of the Windows 11 taskbar

Tags: vb.net, windows-11

As we know, Microsoft choosed not to display seconds in Windows 11 system tray taskbar. Thus, I decided to create a little tool.

A simple timer and a label to show seconds next to the clock.
The code I'm using is:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
        Me.Location = New Point(1891, 1029)
        Me.Size = New Size(21, 18)

        Me.TransparencyKey = Color.LightBlue
        Me.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.Text = ":" + Format(Now, "ss")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Always on top property is on true but if I click on the taskbar the form will disappear from there.
Is there a way to fix it?
thanks

Comment: A must-read: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413

Comment: There's already [a way to make the clock on the taskbar display seconds](https://www.howtogeek.com/325096/how-to-make-windows-10s-taskbar-clock-display-seconds/).

Comment: mate you should read as well my question. 1) I'm not trying to put on top of an already on top form. 2) I'm talking about windows 11 and not windows 10, so the register key you are talking about doesn't work.

Comment: 1) The taskbar is a special type of window; so, you _are_ trying to put your form on top of another window. 2) Apparently, you're right. It looks like that trick [doesn't work](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/report-an-issue/windows-11-cannot-show-seconds-on-taskbar-clock/m-p/2825214) on Windows 11 so far (I shouldn't have assumed that it does; my bad). P.S. That wasn't really my downvote :)

Comment: ok.. But i didn't say I can't put that on top.. I alreay can put the form on top of the taskbar. It stays. Just if i click anywhere in the taskbar or simply i just open a new app from taskbar, it looses the focus like if I minimized it...

Comment: Which is exactly the point of the blog post linked in my first comment (remember: the taskbar is a window and it wants to stay on top too).

Comment: I solved adding me.topmost=true to the timer tick event.

Comment: I'm probably not going to convince you that that's a terrible "solution" but anyway, here's a quote from the first link above: _'For many of these “I want to be the X-est”-type questions, you can often come up with some sort of hack, where you run a timer that periodically checks whether you are still X, and if not, pushes you back into the X-position. And then you stop and think, “What if two programs did this?” and realize that it’s a bad idea. At least I hope you do.'_

Comment: mate it's a very very very simple utility that does its easy job. Don't know which kind of solution you mean I should implement in order to make it work, but that it's more than enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I decided to keep developing this little tool and for some reasons, the position of the form was moving up everytime there was a notification, so I end up forcing the position using the follow code inside of a [**System.Timers.Timer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0) object that fires its [**Timer.Tick**](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.tick?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event every 0,1 seconds (100 milliseconds)

```
 Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
        Me.Location = New Point(1897, 1039)
        Me.Size = New Size(21, 18)
        Me.TransparencyKey = Color.LightBlue
        Me.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
        Label1.Text = Format(Now, "ss")
        Me.TopMost = True
```

Simple, but efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It is disappearing because it is losing focus. If you want it to continuously keep focus or "refocus", you can introduce a hacky method that will refocus the form on each timer tick.

So you could try adding `Me.Focus()` to the `timer1_tick` event.

An example of this was shared on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821585/keep-form-always-on-top-of-taskbar).

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer.. Unfortunately it doesn't work, the form looses its focus as soon as i click anywhere in the taskbar.

Comment: I solved adding me.topmost=true to the timer tick event. Thanks!